# Bash script to get specific user(s) id and processes count

Tags: linux, bash

I need bash script to count processes of SPECIFIC users or all users. We can enter 0, 1 or more arguments. For example

```
./myScript.sh root deamon
```

should execute like this:

```
root      92
deamon     8
2 users has total processes: 100
```

If nothing is entered as parameter, then all users should be listed:

```
uuidd      1
awkd       2
daemon     1
root     210
kklmn      6
  5 users has total processes: 220
```

What I have till now is script for all users, and it works fine (with some warnings). I just need part where arguments are entered (some kind of filter results). Here is script for all users:

```
cntp = 0  #process counter
cntu = 0  #user counter

ps aux |
awk 'NR>1{tot[$1]++; cntp++}
     END{for(id in tot){printf "%s\t%4d\n",id,tot[id]; cntu++} 
     printf "%4d users has total processes:%4d\n", cntu, cntp}'
```

Comment: You can pass variables to `awk`. Like `awk -v args="$1,$2"` then you can `split` the `args` inside `awk 'BEGIN{..}` to make it an array and inside `for (id in tot) { here }` check if `id` is one of the args.

Comment: @KamilCuk I dont know is there 0, 1, 2 or more arguments. How to take a list and list just users from that list?

Comment: Just do a loop checking if `$i=NULL`

Comment: So join arguments with a comma. Like `args="$(IFS=, echo "$@")"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

users=$@
args=()
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  # all processes
  args+=(ax)
else
  # user processes, comma-separated list of users
  args+=(-u${users// /,})
fi

# print the user field without header
args+=(-ouser=)

ps "${args[@]}" | awk '
  { tot[$1]++ }
  END{ for(id in tot){ printf "%s\t%4d\n", id, tot[id]; cntu++ }
  printf "%4d users has total processes:%4d\n", cntu, NR}'
```

The `ps` arguments are stored in array `args` and list either all processes with `ax` or user processes in the form `-uuser1,user2` 
and `-ouser=` only lists the user field without header.

In the `awk` script I only removed the `NR>1` test and variable `cntp` which can be replaced by `NR`.

Possible invocations:

```
./myScript.sh
./myScript.sh root daemon
./myScript.sh root,daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
ps axo user |
awk -v args="$(IFS=,; echo "$*")" '
    BEGIN {
        # split args on comma
        split(args, users, ",");
        # associative array with user as indexes
        for (i in users) {
            enabled[users[i]] = 1
        }
    }
    NR > 1 {
        tot[$1]++;
        cntp++;
    }
    END {
        for(id in tot) {

            # if we passed some arguments
            # and its disabled
            if (length(args) && enabled[id] == 0) {
                continue
            }

            printf "%s\t%4d\n", id, tot[id];
            cntu++;
        } 
        printf "%4d users has total processes:%4d\n", cntu, cntp
    }
'
```

[Tested in repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FaintAliceblueSampler).

Comment: Hello, works with some small errors (for total processes it counts all processes, not just from listed users). Of course, this is easy to correct. Other thing are ok. 
Upvote, pity I cant accept 2 answers. Thanks for helping