# Bash script to count total users and total procs

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I've created this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE="$(date)"
USERSCOUNT=0
PROCSCOUNT=0

OUTPUT="UserID Count\n"
echo "$DATE"
for user in "$@"; do
    (( USERSCOUNT++ ))
    USERS[${#USERS[@]}]="$user"
    PROCS=$(ps -u "$user" | wc -l)
    PROCSCOUNT=$((PROCSCOUNT+PROCS))
    OUTPUT="$OUTPUT\n${USERS[${#USERS[@]}-1]} ${PROCS[${#PROCS[@]}-1]}"
done

BOTTOM="$USERSCOUNT USERS, TOTAL PROCESSES: $PROCS"

echo -ne "$OUTPUT" | column -t
echo "$BOTTOM"
sleep 5
```

done

If I run it like this: `./count-user-procs` the output is this:

```
Sun Feb 23 02:48:30 EET 2020
UserID   Count
_rspamd  5
postfix  17
dovecot  4
3 USERS, TOTAL PROCESSES: 4
```

Now at the end I want to add something like:
**3 USERS, TOTAL PROCESSES: 21**

Where total user is the number of users specified when running the script and total processes is the sum of the processes of each of the users. Not sure how I am supposed to do that... So basically I just have to add to the script the total process number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script to get specific user(s) id and processes count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319128/bash-script-to-get-specific-users-id-and-processes-count)

Comment: Pretty much yes, I wanted to add that to my current script which outputs everything exactly how I need it. I'll update my question, I've added also the count for the user number

Comment: Well that I did already, I'm just trying to count the total number of processes based on  the number of processes each user has

Comment: Somehow I have to make that PROCSCOUNT to reflect the correct value

Comment: Tried that already, it outputs the total processes number of the last user

Comment: `$PROCSCOUNT` has the correct value, but you are printing `$PROCS`

Answer (score 1):

With bash and an associative array/hash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array # associative array

# collect data
for user in "$@"; do
  array[$user]=$(ps -u "$user" | wc -l)
  sum=$(($sum+${array[$user]}))
done

# print data
(
  echo "UserID Count"
  for user in "${!array[@]}"; do
    echo "$user ${array[$user]}"
  done 
) | column -t

echo "Users: ${#array[@]}"
echo "Sum: $sum"
```